# Convert Pewee query results into list

Tags: python, peewee

I'm building a Flask app with Peewee and PostgreSQL. I want to get a list of integers ids from a table.

```
def get_tagsID(self):
    return tag_list.select(tag_list.id).order_by(tag_list.tagGroup)
```

Then in the html file I have this:

```
{% for t in test %}
{{ t.id }},
{% endfor %}
```

Which creates this:    `29, 30, 32, 26,`

And now, I want to make a proper list out of it, in the app.py file

```
tagList = []
tags = modelFinance.Finance().get_tagsID()
for t in tags:
    tagList.append(t)
session['filter'] = tagList
```

Gives this error:

`TypeError: <modelFinance.tag_list object at 0x758d9430> is not JSON serializable`

How can I get a list of ids from this query?

Comment: What is tag_list?

Comment: I am guessing that the tag_list.select() sometimes returns None or something else that is not iterable. So you probably want to test whether `res` actually contains any results before looping over it.

Comment: please see edited question